# Regarding jenkins Slave configurations

Tags: jenkins

Is there any mechanism in Hudson/Jenkns which automatically invokes the slave machine which ever free for any jobs.

Ex. I have a job which is tied with a node, and another job is tied to same node, so instead of queuing is there any way Hudson automatically tie the queued job to another available node if any?

And is that okay to connect same slaves with multiple masters.?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the Swarm plugin [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Swarm+Plugin)

> This plugin enables slaves to
>   auto-discover nearby Hudson master and
>   join it automatically, thereby forming
>   an ad-hoc cluster.

Answer (score 15):

I would suggest, that you don't tie the jobs to a specific node, but to a label, and assign that label to all nodes, on which the jobs can be executed.

And as far as i know, a slave can only connect to one master instance. But you can of course run multiple jenkins slave instance on one physical server instance.

Comment: +1 the label is the way to go, or increase the number of build executors for the client so 2 builds can run in parallel. :)

Comment: Thanks Peter, I have one more question if we can use VM as master and no jobs on that VM and slaves are physical machines.?

Comment: Sure, that should be no problem. If the master only schedules the builds and doesn't execute builds itself, it shouldn't consume much power.